# rewrite url and redirect to extended page in silverstripe

Tags: php, .htaccess, silverstripe

I'm kinda a beginner in Silverstripe and I want specific urls to be redirected to custom page that extends the class page.

I added the rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*-i(\d+)$ inv/test.php [NC,QSA]
```

which detect my urls successfully and redirect to test.php

I have a custom page class that extends the class page, I want somehow to load an instance of my custom class page.

**Edited:** I have many urls that have specifc formats, something like: www.mysite.com/segment1-segment2-segment3-i543 where that last number is the id of the item,but all these urls are not pages in the cms.  My rule in the .htaccess detect these type of urls. I want to render these pages using my template for this custom class.

Comment: Just set the page type of the redirection page to your custom class. That's possible via CMS, Settings tab.

Comment: @wmk I edited my questions, the pages are not created in the cms.

Comment: well, you need to get the route to a custom controller, based on the parameters in that controller you can choose what class or template to use.